# Error Compiling libc++ using Clang 3.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: clang, libc++

When I try to compile libc++ (`libcxx`) on my Ubuntu 12.04 with LLVM 3.0 and Clang 3.0 i get the error

```
+ clang++ -c -g -Os -fPIC -std=c++0x -fstrict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wnewline-eof -Wpadded -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wstrict-overflow=4 -nostdinc++ -I../include ../src/stdexcept.cpp
../src/stdexcept.cpp:18:10: fatal error: 'cxxabi.h' file not found
#include <cxxabi.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Where should I put cxxabi.h? It's currently in the following places

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cxxabi.h
/usr/include/c++/4.6/cxxabi.h
/usr/include/c++/4.7/cxxabi.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that any of these cxxabi.h will work.  The only thing std except.cpp is looking for is if it is being used with [libc++abi](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/), which will be false for all 3 of your cxxabi.h.